# ¿Cómo comparo dos objetos en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo un programa en el que una serie de objetos con su precio se almacenan en un hashtable:

```
public class Producto {
    private int cod;
    private String nombre;
    private double precio;

    public Producto(int cod, String nombre, double precio) {
        this.cod = cod;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public int getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof Producto) {
            Producto tmpProducto = (Producto) obj;

            if (this.cod == tmpProducto.cod
                && this.nombre.equals(tmpProducto.nombre)
                && this.precio == tmpProducto.precio) { 
                return true; 
            } else { 
                return false; 
            }

        } else { 
            return false; 
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(cod, nombre, precio);
    }
```

Luego tengo este método que compara los objetos pero siempre me devuelve false. Espero que puedan ayudarme. gracias

```
Hashtable<Producto, Integer> productos = new Hashtable<Producto, Integer>(); 

    public boolean hayStock(Producto p){
            if(productos.contains(p)){
                if(productos.get(p) > 0){
                    System.out.println("Quedan " +productos.get(p)+ " unidades");
                    return true;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("No quedan productos");
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("El producto no existe");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: La implementación del método `equals()` debe funcionar si dos objetos tienen los mismos valores en sus atributos. Asegúrate de que realmente existan objetos iguales en `Hashtable productos`, o agrega la parte del código donde llenas esta estructura.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Entonces ¿ese método estaría bien? ¿el problema estría en los objetos de la tabla?

Comment: A priori diría que si. Me parece que el problema es que no tienes objetos iguales en el `Hashtable`.

Comment: Esta es la prueba que estoy haciendo en un test. insertaProducto mete el producto en el hashtable.
@Test
    public void testHayStock() {
        System.out.println("hayStock");       
        Producto p1 = new Producto(1, "Mandos", 50.00);
        almacen.insertaProducto(p1, 50);
        boolean result = almacen.hayStock(p1);
        assertEquals(true, result);
    }

Comment: Y el código del método `insertaProducto()`?

Comment: Aquí está.
public void insertaProducto(Producto p, int cantidad){          
                productos.put(p, cantidad);
                System.out.println("Producto insertado");         
    }

Comment: Tu definición de la estructura  `productos` es como esta `Hashtable<Integer, Producto> productos;`??

Comment: Sí, pero primero se le mete un producto y luego la cantidad, es decir Hashtable<Producto, Integer>

Comment: El problema que estás teniendo es que utilizas instancias de la clase producto como llave en tu `Hashtable` y como valor la cantidad(un `Integer`). Luego en el método `hayStock()` utilizas el método `contains()` de la clase `Hashtable` para determinar si el producto para el cual buscas sus existencias existe en tu `Hashtable`, para luego ver si tiene existencias. Ese método `contains()`, siempre te va a retornar `false` porque lo que hace es ver si en el `Hashtable` existe el valor que le pasas como parámetros, pero tus valores son las cantidades. Utiliza `containsKey()` en vez de `contains()`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73232/discussion-between-e-betanzos-and-pacopepe).

Comment: Tenías razón, he cambiado contains por containsKey y ahora sí pasa la prueba. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, llevaba tiempo sin saber cómo resolver el problema.

Comment: De todos modos no es correcto que utilices `Producto` como clave de un `Hashtable`. Te recomiendo que le des otra vuelta a eso.

Comment: Es por un ejercicio de clase que me lo propone así, creo que por eso he tenido que formar tanto jaleo.